# Apply Default Values when Instantiating a new Record

Tags: java, jooq

I see that jOOQ is also adding the default value to its metadata:

```
public class Kampagne extends TableImpl<KampagneRecord> {

  this.AKTIV = createField("AKTIV", 
               SQLDataType.VARCHAR(1).nullable(false)
                 .defaultValue(DSL.field("'J' ", SQLDataType.VARCHAR)), 
               this, 
               "die Kampagne ist aktiv, d.h. noch nicht abgeschlossen (markiert) resp. ist abgeschlossen (nicht markiert)", 
               new Varchar2ToBooleanConverter());
```

Is there a way to add these default values when creating a new Record?

So that this test will succeed?

```
KampagneRecord record = new KampagneRecord();

assertTrue(record.getAktiv();
```

Why I need this you may ask? I use the Record in a UI and want that the checkboxes are already set to the default value based on the Record that is bound to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not implemented. There are a variety of possible `DEFAULT` expressions that need to be evaluated, possibly by the database, in order to get the correct value. A simple case is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which should correspond:

1. To the server (database) time, not the client time
2. To the time the record is actually created, not some prior moment when a client creates the client record model.

In your particular case, it would obviously work as it is a constant without any contextual ambiguity. [You could extend the code generator and generate some custom code sections in records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/) (and POJOs if you use them). That custom code section would then contain an instance initialiser, which would be run with every constructor call:

```java
{
    set(KAMPAGNE.AKTIV, true);
    // Other default initialisations
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the parser to reverse engineer the `DataType.default_()` value and extract the constant value from the `Param` (if it is a `Param`, or something compatible with a `Param`, such as e.g. `CAST(1 AS INT)`)

Comment: I see. I will go ahead and read about the code generator. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Would be curious to see that. If it works for you, you could publish it on Github or your blog?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I've just thought of another thing. All `DEFAULT` expressions are expressions. Perhaps we could offer a feature where you could easily run a `SELECT` statement containing those expressions, producing the record instead of creating it yourself. This has the cost of an additional server round trip, but would be somewhat more robust.

Comment: If I come up with a solution for my problem I will for sure write about it. And yes a server round trip wouldn't be an issue if we get a populated record.

Comment: OK, cool. Actually, we could detect if a server roundtrip is even needed. If all defaults are constant, then we could avoid it, which would make this a really nice to have feature. I have created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8683

Comment: Superb support. Thank you!